# Using string array in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to do some scraping using Python 2.7.2. I've just started with Python and unfortunately it is not as intuitive as I thought it will be. I try to collect all specific -s from all pages. I don't know how to accumulate results from all pages in string array. So far I'm getting results from 1 page only. I know that this is a super easy question for people who write in python. So please help me. Here is the code:

```
import urllib
import re
j=1
while j<10:
    url="http://www.site.com/search?page=" + str(j) + "&query=keyword"
    print url
    htmlfile=urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext=htmlfile.read()
    regex='<span class="class33">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern=re.compile(regex)
    spans=re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    #spans[j] insttead of spans doesn't work
    #spans.append(spans) doesn't work
    j+=1
i=0
while i<len(spans):
    print spans[i]
    i+=1
```

Comment: You are actually making things harder on yourself. I would use BeautifulSoup for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. put all invariant code outside the `for` loop
2. outside the `for` loop init `s` to the empty list

   ```
   s = []
   ```
3. inside the `for` loop

   ```
       s.extend(re.findall(pattern, htmltext))
   ```

If you prefer `s += re.findall(pattern, htmltext)` will do the same

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
spans=re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
```

to

```
spans.extend(re.findall(pattern,htmltext))
```

I'd also change your loop syntax a bit

```
import urllib
import re
spans = []
for j in range(1,11):
    url="http://www.site.com/search?page=" + str(j) + "&query=keyword"
    print url
    htmlfile=urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext=htmlfile.read()
    regex='<span class="class33">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern=re.compile(regex)
    spans.extend(re.findall(pattern,htmltext))
for span in spans:
    print span
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, here is the message:
spans.append(re.findall(pattern,htmltext))
NameError: name 'spans' is not defined

Comment: Sorry see the edit, forgot to initialize spans to an empty list

Answer (score 0):

Before your loop, define spans:

```
spans = []
```

Then in your loop:

```
spans.extend(re.findall(pattern,htmltext))
```

The findall method will return a list.  You want to extend the spans list with the new spans on each iteration.

Comment: still getting an error:
  File "C:\Python27\Debug\mml01.py", line 13, in <module>
    spans.extend(re.findall(pattern,htmltext))
NameError: name 'spans' is not defined

Comment: You need to define spans first before your loop.  spans = []